# Create specific array from a given array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello i need help to extract an array from this array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Casablanca' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'El Jadida' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Fes' (length=3)
```

I'm working with blade form select :

```
echo Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'), 'S');
```

So to use my array i must have the same form that laravel use:

```
array(
    '1' => 'Casablanca',
    '2' => 'El Jadida',
    '3' => 'Fes'
)
```

Comment: A simple loop should do the job - what part did you get stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the framework part, but this should do the trick:

```
// oldA = your array from the question
$newA = array();
foreach($oldA as $v){
    $newA[$v['id']] = $v['name'];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Casablanca
    [2] => El Jadida
    [3] => Fes
)
```

See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/610144).

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop is perfectly fine, but if you want to do it in a single line of code you can use array_combine() and array_column():

```
$arr = array_combine(array_column($arr, 'id'), array_column($arr, 'name'));
```

Comment: `array_column` needs PHP 5.5+